# Details on pre-rendering with AMP HTML

Tags: amp-html

I've seen some mention of pre-rendering with AMP pages. Specifically, the project's how-it-works page (https://www.ampproject.org/how-it-works/) says:

> AMP documents are from the ground up designed to be efficiently pre-renderable. Browsers have long supported pre-rendering through the <link rel=prerender> tag, but they need to be conservative about this mechanism because prerendering can be expensive. With AMP HTML we added the ability to tell a document: render yourself, but only as far as what is visible above the fold and only elements which are not CPU intensive to minimize the cost of pre-rendering.

I'd like to understand more about how the pre-rendering works:

- Is there any further documentation on this pre-rendering? I haven't been able to find any further details.
- Where is the code that implements the pre-rendering?
- If it's not a link with rel=prerender, what's the technique used for pre-rendering?
- How do you indicate to an AMP html page to render in pre-render mode where it only loads above the fold resources, etc.. ?
- Is there some nicely packaged way for someone to use this pre-rendering on their own AMP site (when navigating between pages)?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote about how prerendering works in AMP [in this post](https://medium.com/@cramforce/why-amp-html-does-not-take-full-advantage-of-the-preload-scanner-7e7f788aa94e#.eeiqzkmzj).

We do not yet have great docs on how to use this, but it is one of our goals for this year to provide stable SDKs for web, iOS and Android that has prerendering builtin.

Comment: Thanks for this, but a little light on specific detail. I'm guessing a hidden iframe loads the page to get around poor browser support of prerender via link and also to get round the one prerender limit for those browsers that do support it? Clever. And is this iframe the same size as the current window so AMP automatically only prerenders the images above the current fold?

Comment: I had already seen this link, but as @BazzaDP mentioned, it doesn't really provide detail about how the prerendering works and how to use it.

Comment: This will be documented eventually. You can set a fragment param on the iframe URL to put the doc into prerender mode. In this mode it will only download resources above the fold and no resources that might use a lot of CPU or are privacy sensitive (3p content).